# Non-NULL User input

Tags: c, string, struct

> I'm trying to understand the whole concept of pointers, structures, etc so I've created a program that gets user input for two different books and then swaps the info of the two books. I had no trouble doing that, however, a problem arose- when I pressed *enter* the name of the book would be plain blank and at the output I would, of course, see a blank space. **My problem is, how am I able to limit the user to input any letter (A-Z, a-z) and not blank space?**

A string of characters when input to an array, they get saved in consecutive memory addresses. We also know that 'NULL' is represented as '\0' in arrays.

With the above things in mind, I performed multiple tests in which, **ALL** of them failed to yield the desired results.

Below are some attempts that I made.

***1st Attempt***

```
while (pBook1->name[0] == '\0')
{
    printf("\n Please enter a valid book name: ");
    fgets(pBook1->name, MAX, stdin);
}
```

***2nd Attempt***

```
while (strcmp(pBook1->name, ""))
{
    printf("\n Please enter a valid book name: ");
    fgets(pBook1->name, MAX, stdin);
}
```

Also, consider the following code as the **source code** of my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 50

struct Books
{
    char name[MAX];
    int ID;
    float price;
};

void swap(struct Books *, struct Books *);

void main()
{

    struct Books Book1, Book2, *pBook1, *pBook2;

    pBook1 = &Book1;
    pBook2 = &Book2;

    // Input for the 1st book
    printf("\n 1st Book \n ------------------------------");
    printf("\n Enter the name: ");
    fgets(pBook1->name, MAX, stdin);
    while (pBook1->name[0] == '\0')
    {
        printf("\n Please enter a valid book name: ");
        fgets(pBook1->name, MAX, stdin);
    }
    printf("\n Enter the ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &pBook1->ID);
    printf("\n Enter the price: ");
    scanf("%f", &pBook1->price);

    // Input for the 2nd book
    printf("\n 2nd Book \n ------------------------------");
    printf("\n Enter the name: ");
    fgets(pBook2->name, MAX, stdin);
    while (pBook2->name[0] == '\0')
    {
        printf("\n Please enter a valid book name: ");
        fgets(pBook2->name, MAX, stdin);
    }
    printf("\n Enter the ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &pBook2->ID);
    printf("\n Enter the price: ");
    scanf("%f", &pBook2->price);

    printf("\n Let's swap the info of the two books...");

    swap(pBook1, pBook2);

    printf("\n The info of the two books is now:");

    printf("\n------------------------------ \n 1st Book \n ------------------------------------");
    printf("\n Name \t\t ID \t Price \n %s \t\t %d \t %f", pBook1->name, pBook1->ID, pBook1->price);

    printf("\n------------------------------ \n 2nd Book \n ------------------------------------");
    printf("Name \t\t ID \t Price \n %s \t\t %d \t %f", pBook2->name, pBook2->ID, pBook2->price);
}

 void swap(struct Books *pB1, struct Books *pB2)
 {
   char temp[MAX];

   strcpy(temp, pB1->name);
   strcpy(pB1->name, pB2->name);
   strcpy(pB2->name, temp);

   int tempID = pB1->ID, tempPrice = pB1->price;

   pB1->ID = pB2->ID;
   pB2->ID = tempID;

   pB1->price = pB2->price;
   pB2->price = tempPrice;
 }
```

Comment: Note that `NULL` and `\0` are conceptually different. `NULL` indicates that an address is unset, and `\0` indicates the end of a c string, and is called the "null terminator".

Comment: @okovko Does that mean that all arrays are by default <code>NULL</code> if they have no initial values?

Comment: No. Any uninitialized value in C and C++ has an undefined value - it can be anything. Typically, it will be zero when your program begins running, and after it has executed for a while, it'll be values that you've used all over your code.

Answer (score 1):

`fgets` reads until it encounters `EOF`, `\n` or `N-1` bytes have been read. So if a user of your program presses enter, it will read `\n` and stop. Which means that `pBook1->name[0] == '\n'`. That is why your check for equality with `""` fails and why `pBook1->name[0] == '\0'` fails.

See this [example](https://repl.it/repls/UnfoldedTransparentFlash).

That means that you need to check for `\n` and `\0` in case the user entered `Ctrl-D` which is how you enter `EOF` on *nix systems.

Answer (score 0):

When you press enter `pBook1->name[0]` will become `\n`. You can use some functions as `strlen` to be sure there something in name.